# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') when deploying to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

When I set a variable through useState, first of all, data is loaded from local storage. On the local server everything works fine, but on Github Pages everything breaks and it returns the variable favoriteCats as Null. What could be the reason?
I tried changing localStorage to sessionStorage, didn't help.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios'

import './App.css';
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import CatsList from "../CatsList/CatsList";
import FavoriteCats from "../CatsList/FavoriteCats";

function App() {
  const [catsList, setCatsList] = useState([]);

    const [favoriteCats, setFavoriteCats] = useState(() => {
        const cats = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("favoriteCats"));
        if (cats !== null) {
            return cats
        } else return []
    });

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
      return function () {
          document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
      }
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
      if (fetching) {
          axios.get(`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?format=json&limit=15&_page=${currentPage}`,
              {headers: {"x-api-key": "03b1c2d3-fb3d-4363-9e71-949a93d8d9f8"}})
              .then(res =>  {
                  setCatsList(catsList => [...catsList, ...res.data])
                  setCurrentPage(prevState => prevState + 1)
              })
              .finally(() => setFetching(false))
      }
  }, [fetching])


    const scrollHandler = (e) => {
      if (e.target.documentElement.scrollHeight - (e.target.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) < 100) {
            setFetching(true)
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setFavoriteCats(JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('favoriteCats')))

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        localstorage.setItem('favoriteCats', JSON.stringify(favoriteCats));
    },[favoriteCats])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<CatsList list={catsList} setFavoriteCats={setFavoriteCats} favoriteCats={favoriteCats}/>} />
            <Route path={'/favorite'} element={<FavoriteCats favoriteCats={favoriteCats} setFavoriteCats={setFavoriteCats}/>} />
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error logs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFiDV.png)

Link on my Github repository: https://github.com/sanny410/frontend-challenge
Link on Deploy: https://sanny410.github.io/frontend-challenge/

Comment: So `setItem` doesn't work?

Comment: setItem gets null and puts it into local storage

Comment: What is this supposed to do if you already set the cats from the local storage? `useEffect(() => {
        setFavoriteCats(JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('favoriteCats')))

    }, []);`

Comment: How `CatsList` looks like?

Comment: Yes, it was really redundant. You pointed to the right place, everything worked, thanks @KonradLinkowski!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code caused the state to be set to `null`

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFavoriteCats(JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('favoriteCats')))
}, []);
```

Removing it fixed the problem as the valid parsing is already done here:

```
const [favoriteCats, setFavoriteCats] = useState(() => {
  const cats = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("favoriteCats"));
  if (cats !== null) {
    return cats
  } else return []
});
```